# Not redirecting the nodejs page while adding heavy data in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asyncsocket

I am adding heavy data to mongo db through looping as below

```
function updateData() {
    for (l = 0; l < 10000 ,l++) {
        db.fbpost.update({pagename:page,'post.id': postsId},{'post.data': posts.data[l]}},{upsert: true},function (err,data){
            if (err) {
                 console.log('could not fetch post from after update', page, err);
            }                   
        })
    }
}
```

i am calling this function from a post method link while the above code inserting data into db, and parallely  i was unable to redirect other links, it was blocked by the loop. So i tried to make the for loop to run async like below but could not help even it was looping continuously without allowing me to access the other page.

```
function forloop(){
            if(i < posts.data.length){
                i++;
                setTimeout(forloop(), 0);
            }
        }
        forloop();
```

Comment: What do you mean by accessing other pages? As in are you trying to send an HTTP redirect before starting to insert data into mongodb?

Comment: yes i am trying to send a HTTP redirect after starting to insert data into mongodb..

Comment: Can you post how you are redirecting?

Comment: was redirecting from a function as res.redirect('/index')  and have another file where i handle '/index' in which i have this app.get('/index',function(req, res){ res.render(index) })

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have sent the `Location` header. Check if you have missed `response.end();`.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  res.writeHead(302, {'Location': 'http://google.com'});
  res.end(); // End the response

}).listen(1337);
```

Comment: no that is all working correctly in redirecting .but the for loop above i posted makes to wait the the redirect as it is in loop and inserting data to db.

Comment: That's async, and since you have added a `setTimeout`, it is not blocking in any way. If possible, show the complete file in pastebin.